# OS is slowing down and shuts down frequently

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, shutdown

TL;DR: My computer is significantly slow,shutting down too. I suspect it's related to not enough partitions.I am a linux noob.

[image: Screenshot of the partitions]

Hello everyone!
A couple of days ago I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1. During the installation, the computer got stuck and after 30 minutes it restarted.
I have dual booth with windows 7,  and I couldn't access Ubuntu and windows.
I tried formatting Ubuntu's partition and installing again, but the system was so slow, that I couldn't work with it.

Than I installed instead Linux Mint 19 (based on the Ubuntu 18.04.1), to try whether it will be faster. It wasn't. Same speed but now I get also computer shut downs.

As an inexperienced linux user, I have reason to believe that I might have made a mistake during the partition part of the installation.

Can someone look at it, and help my understand whether it's the problem or maybe something else?
Edit: While my computer is exceptionally slow, i took a screenshot of top [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl6mZ.png)

Comment: (1) Have you made backups of important files? Maybe your HDD is dying. (2) Is Windows also affected? (3) How much free space is available on Linux system partition? (4) Have you run memtest?

Comment: 1) Increase swap portion amount. Min equal to ram size. 2) Use ext4 file format for Linux portion.3) Check error log. You can install Gnome logs to make it easy.  4) confirm you have all the required device drivers.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, I will back up my data asap. Windows was always slow, and now even slower. It tooks 15 minutes to get to the login screen and a slower restart. I posted on the post a photo of the partitions, I hope it's sufficient. What is memtest?

Comment: Thanks Aravind, My swap portion is now 512MB. I have 4GB of ram, you really think I should increase it to 4 GB? I did use ext4 for the linux portion. How do I confirm having all the required device drivers?

Comment: If Windows was working just fine before, it's unlikely to be drivers, since Windows would have had the drivers needed. The number and size of partitions and the swap space size won't generally cause spontaneous reboots. It's likely to be either failing or dead hardware or the partitioner screwed things up on the disk (which can be fixed by backing up your files you don't want to lose, burning a Windows 10 and Ubuntu ISO to two DVDs or USBs, erasing the disk, reinstalling Windows, using Windows to shrink the Windows partition,&using an Ubuntu installer to add a partition to the new empty space.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't need a swap partition if you install from scratch rather than upgrading from 16.04. It uses a resizable swap file on your main partition when installed from scratch, so you only need an ext4 partition for `/`. You can also try Ubuntu out on VirtualBox on Windows if you don't want to go through quite so much effort.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help, T. Rex was right. apparently my fan didn't function anymore.